# Traffic between EC2 nodes in same security group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have node1 and node2 in security group sg1, and node3 and node4 in security group sg2. I want incoming traffic for node3 and node4 to come only on port 9600 and from sg1, so I provide source security group as sg1 while creating sg2. Now I want node3 and node4 to communicate on port 9700. Do I need to open port 9700 or not as both these nodes belong to same security group? Also, If I need to open port 9700, then I can't provide source security group as sg2 (because I would be creating sg2 at this moment).

How to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, you need to open port even if they belong to the same security group, adding itself as a source.
- You could create the groups and add the rules later, thus providing the source security group as sg2, that already exists.